# python @property setter delegation

Tags: python

I have an object with a bunch `@property` getters and setters on it. I want to delegate to that object, including delegating the getting and setting. I also want to be able to override some setters in the delegating class. Delegation as described [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-is-delegation.htm) works for getters but not for setters. Is there a simple way to do this short of verbosely duplicating all of the `@property` setters?

For example, in the following the underlying `@a.setter` is never hit:

```
class A:
  _a = 'A.a'
  _b = 'A.b'

  @property
  def a(self):
    print('A.a.getter')
    return self._a

  @a.setter
  def a(self, a):
    print('A.a.setter')
    self._a = a

  @property
  def b(self):
    print('A.b.getter')
    return self._b

  @b.setter
  def b(self, b):
    print('A.b.setter')
    self._b = b

class B(object):
  _A = None

  def __init__(self, A):
    self._A = A

  @property
  def b(self):
    print('B.b.getter')
    return self._A.b

  @b.setter
  def b(self, b):
    print('B.b.setter')
    self._A.b = b

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self._A, name)

b = B(A())
print(b.a)
b.a = 123
b.b = 456
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `__setattr__` be `setattr(self._A, name, value)` for delegation to work?

Comment: No that doesn't work. The __setattr__() in the example code is really just do nothing boiler plate. If you remove it, behavior is identical. I was expecting I'd put the logic to access the setter in there... I've removed it from sample code to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you are using `__setattr__` but this works for me:

```
class A(object):
  _a = 'A.a'

  @property
  def a(self):
    print('A.a.getter')
    return self._a

  @a.setter
  def a(self, a):
    print('A.a.setter')
    self._a = a

class B(object):
  _A = None

  def __init__(self, A):
    self._A = A
    self.b = 'B.b'

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self._A, name)

  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    try:
        super(B, self).__setattr__(name, value)
    except AttributeError:
        setattr(self._A, name, value)

b = B(A())
print(b.a)
b.a = 78
```

Output:

```
A.a.getter
A.a
A.a.setter
```

*Update:* In Python 2 you must use [new-style classes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass).

Comment: Hit and issue with this in that I can't override properties in `B`. Part of the point in delegation is to be able to do this on some properties.

Comment: @spinkus Right, I was only thinking of the use case of adding new properties or methods to an object through delegation. If you want to have that "overriding" behavior you just need to change the order in `B.__setattr__`, I've edited the answer with the fix.