# Is a simple property delegation possible?

Tags: python, properties

In the code below, all `Test()` objects depend on a single `Aux()` helper. The helper has a property `prop`. What I want sounds simple: to export that property (and only that property) through the `Test` class API.

Indeed it is very simple to write it explicitly:

```
class Aux:
    def __init__(self):
        self._prop = 0 

    @property
    def prop(self):
        print("read:", self._prop)
        return self._prop

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, val):
        print("write:", val)
        self._prop = val 

    # other Aux methods here

class Test: 
    _aux = Aux()

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._aux.prop

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, val):
        self._aux.prop = val 

    # other Test methods here

# try it out:
t = Test()
print(t.prop) # read: 0
t.prop = 123  # write: 123
print(t.prop)
```

However I thought for a moment I could use a direct reference somehow. This is wrong:

```
class Test: 
    prop = Aux.prop     # WRONG! (references `_prop` attr in this class, not in the helper)
    prop = Aux().prop   # WRONG! (equals to simple prop = 0)
```

but maybe:

```
class Test: 
    prop = property(...)   # BUT HOW?
```

But after a while I could not find a simple `prop=...` solution. Now I'm curious. Does it exist?

---

There is a similar question [python @property setter delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44331810/5378816) but it does not help me. I don't want to delegate everything.

Comment: `class Test: aux = Aux()` works if you make it an actual [*descriptor*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), not just a class with a property.

Comment: You are mixing up class and instance attribute here. This might lead to confusions like when you change one property's values and suddenly all change.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, but I cannot tweak existing `Aux`

Comment: @KlausD. That is OK in this case. The real `Aux` represents some kind of global storage, practically a singleton.